# Group by hour - specifying the minute to start at

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I've got a query that gets data for a specific day and groups it by hour:

```
SELECT id, timetag
FROM table
-- rest of long query
-- rest of long query
GROUP BY  DATEPART(YEAR, timetag), DATEPART(MONTH, timetag), DATEPART(DAY, timetag), DATEPART(HOUR, timetag)
```

and that works fine.
But is it possible to specify the time the hour starts? The data being retrieved is in 15 minute increments, i.e. there is data for 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45, 13:00, 13:15 and so on. So when it is grouping by hour it is grouping the data for 12:00, 12:15, 12:30 and 12:45, then for 13:00, 13:15, 13:30 and 13:45 and so on. I would like to group the data by hour but start at 15 minutes past the hour, so the grouping would be for 12:15, 12:30, 12:45 and 13:00, then next grouping would start at 13:15 and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

Using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Your query as posted should give an error like `Column 'id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: True, I wasn't paying attention to the SELECT, just typed it in quickly as it was the GROUP BY part of the query I was focusing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting 15 minutes and using that for the grouping:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, new_timetag),
       DATEPART(MONTH, new_timetag),
       DATEPART(DAY, new_timetag),
       DATEPART(HOUR, new_timetag),
       COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT t.*, dateadd(minute, -15, timetag) as new_timetag
      FROM table t
     ) t
-- rest of long query
-- rest of long query
GROUP BY  DATEPART(YEAR, new_timetag),
          DATEPART(MONTH, new_timetag),
          DATEPART(DAY, new_timetag),
          DATEPART(HOUR, new_timetag);
```

Because subtracting 15 minutes can affect all the date/time parts, I moved it to a subquery so the code only has it once.

Comment: You can't select `id` or `timetag` without grouping on them